# Wrong layout is selected for a screen density

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have three layouts :

- /layout/layout.xml
- /layout-xhdpi/layout.xml
- /layout-xxhdpi/layout.xml

And i have two emulators :

- Nexus 5x with Api level 28 screen size 1080x1920 420dpi
- Pixel 3xl with Api 28 screen size 1440x2960 560dpi

What do I expect?

- Nexux 5x should select the layout in /layout-xhdpi/layout.xml
- Pixel 3xl should select layout in /layout-xxhdpi/layout.xml

What happens instead?

Both devices select layout in layout-xxhdpi.

I have also tried to replace by folder such as layout-sw420dp and layout-sw560dp one or both emulator select another layout.

Why does this happen, is there something?

Comment: After running the command : adb shell dumpsys window
I got the output for Nexus 5x -> 
mGlobalConfiguration={1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h618dp 420dpi

and for Pixel 3xl -> 
mGlobalConfiguration={1.0 310mcc260mnc [en_US] ldltr sw411dp w411dp h748dp 560dpi

Is this normal that they have the same sw and w or a formula explain this ?

Comment: Also, how both may be considered as xxhdpi ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are running one project on two devices you must go as per following approch:

1. set the `setContentView(R.layout-xhdpi.layout.xml);` in java
2. then tun the project on Nexux 5x
3. now set the `setContentView(R.layout-xxhdpi.layout.xml);` in java
4. then run the project on Pixel 3xl

If anything concerns you please leave a comment

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is this serious ?

Comment: Well thats the answer i know ,there can be a different approch also which i dont know yet

Comment: This is the responsibility of the system to select the right layout based on the configuration, but on this issue, the selected layout is not the one i expect for a given device(emulator) configuration

Answer (score 0):

First get the screen size of device by using:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

After this you can use if else statement like

```
if(height==first phone display height)
{set the setContentView(R.layout-xhdpi.layout.xml);}
Else{setContentView(R.layout-xxhdpi.layout.xml); 
}
```

Remember you need to pass exect screen size at place of first phone screen height